# How can I get the information of the file in a specific directory path such as file mime type and file name by php function?

Tags: php

For example, scan the directory of /favor to get the name and type of the unknown file inside this folder using php

Comment: Did you check my (@user2727841) code...

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of [`finfo_file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) in PHP.

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

**`OUTPUT:`**

```
text/html
image/gif
application/vnd.ms-excel
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this it'll get the file name and extensions

```
$files=glob("files/*");    // files is directory name and * mean all types of files    
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file."<br />";
}
```

It'll return file name and format!!!