# How can I get the file type and file name of a unknown file from a specific folder by PHP?

Tags: php

for example, I have a unknown file just uploaded from my website to my local directory htdoc/myWeb/upload/ . I want to scan the upload folder to get the mime type (e.g. text/plain) and the name of the unknown file by php function. Which function could I use?
The format string that I want the function to return is like as follow:

text.txt for file name and text/plain for file type.

Comment: See the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523981/how-can-i-get-the-information-of-the-file-in-a-specific-directory-path-such-as-f/21524561#21524561

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
         foreach (glob("/htdoc/myWeb/upload/*") as $filename) {
              echo $filename . '-->' . finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
         }
    finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

p.s.: you will get absolute path in $filename e.g. /htdoc/myWeb/upload/text.txt

Comment: I have got an error message :Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs\myWeb\find.php on line 2

How can I solve it? My php version is 5.5.6

Comment: You must install Fileinfo PECL extension, see here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php
or you can use deprecated function mime_content_type($filename);

Comment: is the extension enabled by default as of php 5.3.0?

Comment: You can search and uncomment string **extension=fileinfo.so** in your php.ini file, and restart web server, if Fileinfo extension allready installed.

Comment: I have enabled the extension and restart the server. However, I have got an blank page when I execute the php script.. I have a file called test.txt in /upload.

Comment: Maybe you use not absolute path to upload folder.
It can be /var/www/htdoc/myWeb/upload/ or some like this.

Comment: Also if you run script from your site root directory, you can use 
`glob(driname(__FILE__) . "/upload/*")` string.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Now I can find the file name and the file type by glob(driname(__FILE__). However, how can I do to extract the file name without the directory path. e.g. get the string of the file name Tulips.jpg from the string of C:\xampp\htdocs\myWeb/upload/Tulips.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To get only file name w.o. directory path you can use some like this:

```
foreach (glob(dirname(__FILE__) . "/upload/*") as $filename) {
   $names = explode('/', $filename);
   $just_file_name = end($names);
   echo $just_file_name . "\n";
}
```